# Запрос к БД Access из C# с использованием переменных в качестве параметра

Tags: c#, access

Выполняя данный запрос в С# выдается ошибка об отсутствии одного или нескольких параметров, здесь sl, sp переменные программы.

```
myOleDbCommand.CommandText = "SELECT Login FROM People WHERE Login=sl AND password=sp";
```

Я пробовал так, но выдает ошибку отсутствия одного или нескольких параметров

```
myOleDbCommand.CommandText = "SELECT Login FROM People WHERE Login="+sl+" AND password="+sp;
```

Comment: myOleDbCommand.CommandText = String.Format("SELECT Login FROM People WHERE Login={0} AND password={1}", sl, sp);

Или я чего то не понимаю?

Comment: @iPro а потом кто-то введет логин `'' OR 1 = 1; DROP TABLE People --`  https://xkcd.com/327/.

Answer (score 2):

Используйте параметры:

```
myOleDbCommand.CommandText = "SELECT Login FROM People WHERE Login=? AND password=?";
// параметры подставляются по порядку, именя можно задать любые
myOleDbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Login", sl);
myOleDbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Password", sp);
```

а лучше - именованные параметры:

```
myOleDbCommand.CommandText = "SELECT Login FROM People WHERE Login=@Login AND password=@Password";
// параметры подставляются по имени, старый Access такое может не переварить
myOleDbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Login", sl);
myOleDbCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", sp);
```

Answer (score -2):

```
myOleDbCommand.CommandText = "SELECT Login FROM People WHERE Login="""+sl+""" AND password="""+sp+""""
```

Но этот код позволяет сделать `SQL-injection`. Подумайте сами, как его можно улучшить/обезопасить.

Answer (score -2):

Вот так работает

```
myOleDbCommand.CommandText = "SELECT Login FROM People WHERE Login=@sl AND password=@sp
```