# System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: "Ошибка синтаксиса в инструкции INSERT INTO."

Tags: c#, база-данных

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace FindYourJob
{
    public partial class Form4 : Form
    {
        public static string connectString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=AntonioDB.mdb;";

        private OleDbConnection myConnection;

        public Form4()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            myConnection = new OleDbConnection(connectString);
            myConnection.Open();
        }
        private void Form4_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            myConnection.Close();
        }
        Random rnd = new Random();
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            long lol = rnd.Next(1000000, 9000000);
            MessageBox.Show("Сохранить?");
            //string query = "INSERT INTO awesome (work_name, salary, age_from, age_to, city, school, qwer, number) VALUES ('" + textBox1.Text + "', " + numericUpDown3.Value + ", " + numericUpDown2.Value + ", " + numericUpDown1.Value + ", '" + comboBox3.SelectedItem + "', '" + comboBox1.SelectedItem + "', '" + comboBox2.SelectedItem + "', '"+lol+"')";
            string query = "INSERT INTO awesome (work_name, salary, age_from, age_to, city, school, qwer, number) VALUES ('" + textBox1.Text + "', " + numericUpDown3.Value + ", " + numericUpDown2.Value + ", " + numericUpDown1.Value + ", '" + comboBox3.SelectedItem + "', '" + comboBox1.SelectedItem + "', '" + comboBox2.SelectedItem + "')";
            MessageBox.Show(query);
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(query, myConnection);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Успешно сохранено!");
        }
```

Прошу обратить внимание на строчку

```cs
//string query = "INSERT INTO awesome (work_name, salary, age_from, age_to, city, school, qwer, number) VALUES ('" + textBox1.Text + "', " + numericUpDown3.Value + ", " + numericUpDown2.Value + ", " + numericUpDown1.Value + ", '" + comboBox3.SelectedItem + "', '" + comboBox1.SelectedItem + "', '" + comboBox2.SelectedItem + "', '"+lol+"')";
string query = "INSERT INTO awesome (work_name, salary, age_from, age_to, city, school, qwer, number) VALUES ('" + textBox1.Text + "', " + numericUpDown3.Value + ", " + numericUpDown2.Value + ", " + numericUpDown1.Value + ", '" + comboBox3.SelectedItem + "', '" + comboBox1.SelectedItem + "', '" + comboBox2.SelectedItem + "')";
```

То, что закомментено вызывает ошибку, то что не закоментенно соответственно не вызывает. Прошу объяснить, в каком месте ошибка.

Выдаваемая ошибка: `System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: "Ошибка синтаксиса в инструкции INSERT INTO."`

[image: как выглядит форма]
[image: и база данных на MS Access]

Comment: Может потому что Вы long пытаетесь передать, попробуйте с int lol, хотя там вроде у вас кавычки в передаче lol, видимо проблема в них

Comment: Я пытался без кавычек, та же ошибка

Comment: Попробуйте переписать запрос с параметрами как в первом ответе в данном вопросе https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/314001/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%BA-%D0%91%D0%94-access-%D0%B8%D0%B7-c-%D1%81-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0

Comment: `MessageBox.Show(query);` - покажите результат вывода. Только не надо скриншотов, просто нажмите Ctrl+C.